# MS Access CurrentDb.execute not working

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I'm currently running a vbscript in MS Access 2010 that retrieves some attachments from MS Outlook and inserts that data into a table in the MS Access database. The issue I have is that I'm trying to update these records after they were inserted (using TransferText) by using CurrentDb.Execute, unfortunately this piece of code doesn't seem to work (no errors thrown, no warnings, nothing):

```
Set Db = CurrentDb
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
With Db
  .Execute "UPDATE HOURLY_ENTITY_STATS SET TIMESTAMP = 'statDate'"
Debug.Print .RecordsAffected & " were updated"
```

So everytime I execute this query, a new value should be added to the column TIMESTAMP (text type) but so far nothing happens.

I did my own research before posting the question here and couldn't find anyone having a similar issue.

If you can think of anything, please let me know!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried using DoCmd.RunSQL and the results were the same, no updates to my rows

Comment: You should have dbFailOnError and DoCmd.SetWarnings True should never be necessary.

Comment: You are sure Timestamp will accept the words `statDate` and that that is what you want? You have tried typing `statDate` into the column? I suspect that this is **not** what you want.

Comment: Hi Remou, thanks for the comments.
1. Tried it already using
    .Execute "UPDATE HOURLY_ENTITY_STATS SET TIMESTAMP = 'statDate'", dbFailOnError
2. The column type is TEXT so yes, it can receive the value 'statDate'

Comment: Does it work if you use `[TIMESTAMP]` in the statement and `dbFailOnError` with the `.Execute` method?  With no `WHERE` clause, that would attempt to update every row in `HOURLY_ENTITY_STATS` ... is that what you wanted?

Comment: You hit the nail in the head Hans, I was missing the brackets. That's nowhere in the documentation

Comment: It's a reserved word.  Plenty more to avoid: http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html Also see the link for the Database Issue Checker utility on that page.

Comment: If you're actually using VBScript instead of VBA, use the value (128) instead of the name of the constant `dbFailOnError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't why I hadn't seen this before but thanks to HansUp I got it to work.
The problem is that I was using a reserve word in the SQL query, so had to encapsulate the column name in brackets [TIMESTAMP]

Thank you all.

Comment: Rather than trying to figure out what is and is not a reserved word, use the convention of prefixing all field names with the table name, or better, the alias. This will save trouble in a great many cases, not just reserved words: `select a.id, b.id, b.name from tablea a inner join tableb b` It also makes your SQL suitable for a number of other databases.